# Git add file/files in an unstaged state

Tags: git

I would like to add new/previously untracked files without staging them so that I can view the diff before adding their changes. Is there a simple way to do this?

I will try to answer my own question since I have wanted to do this for awhile but just looked up  how.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `git add -N FILE1 FILE2` or `git add --intent-to-add FILE1 FILE2` to add a new file as untracked. This way you will be able to view the diff of the file before staging it. You could also just use `git diff --cached` to see the diff of staged changes before committing.

From the `git add` documentation:

```
   -N, --intent-to-add
       Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for the path is placed in the index with no
       content. This is useful for, among other things, showing the unstaged content of such files with git diff and
       committing them with git commit -a.
```